# Is there an element similar to Kryptonite which weakens or kills a Marvel superhero?

Tags: marvel, comics

I listen a lot (and, even guess) that Marvel has copied DC a lot. It got me wondering whether a substance similar to Kryptonite exists in Marvel universe.

Comment: Who says marvel copied DC, also you've now set the scope of your question exclusively to the comics. [Computer says no](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/389jl1/marvel_what_are_some_marvel_equivalents_to/)

Comment: @Edlothiad Quicksilver from Flash.. Hawkeye from Green Arrow.. Namor from Aquaman.. Nova corps from Green Lantern corps.. Ultron from Brainiac.. Rang any bell?

Comment: Sure, you can relate all those to ancient mythologies, so DC just copied older stories?

Comment: Vibranium would absolutely destroy classical Klaw, seeing as he was made of living sound and Vibranium cancels out vibrations.
Of course, Klaw isn't a hero...

Comment: @Edlothiad - Also, namor predates aquaman by a couple years, so it's not universal. DC was first to the punch with a lot, but by no means all of them: https://9gag.com/gag/aKgv6R3/marvel-vs-dc-equivalent-characters

Comment: @JohnP that was certainly going to be my next point, “unless you can confirm x came before y, my question stands”

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that when Stan Lee and Jack Kirby created the Marvel superhero universe, they strived for a more realistic feel that the (at the time) rather silly DC Comics.

A part of that was doing away with silly weaknesses like Superman's vulnerability to kryptonite, Mon-El's vulnerability to lead, Green Lantern's ring not working against yellow, Mordru losing his powers when covered with dirt, and Aquaman not being able to survive more than an hour out of water (but being fine until then).

In my 40+ years of reading Marvel, I can't think of any similar weakness among Marvel characters, apart from Hyperion's vulnerability to argonite - but then, Hyperion is a deliberate Superman pastiche.

Namor does get weaker outside of water, but it is a gradual process, and I don't think he would die if staying out too long, as long as he gets something to drink. A vague similarity to DC's weaknesses is that originally, if Thor lost his hammer for more than a minute, it would revert to a stick and he would revert to Don Blake.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the DC weaknesses:

- Kryptonians: kryptonite
- Martian Manhunter: fire
- golden age Green Lantern: wood
- silver age GL: yellow
- golden/silver age Wonder Woman: bracelets bound by a man (or removed)

are a mechanism to place limits/challenges on characters with nigh-unlimited power.

Marvel has far fewer characters with nigh-unlimited power - at least in part, because their characters had limits that seemed a bit more natural, or more logically tied to the character's origins.

As noted, Hyperion is vulnerable to argonite, but was explicitly intended to be an analog to Superman.

If we look at Marvel's most powerful characters, especially from the early 1960s, we see:

- Thor: reverts to human form after 60 seconds not in contact with Mjolnir (his hammer)
- Hulk: reverts to human under certain circumstances (almost random at first; later, when he becomes calm rather than angry)
- Thing: occasionally returned to human form temporarily (first few years only)
- Iron Man: armor chestplate kept him alive (into the 1970s, at least)
- Doctor Strange: Must speak and/or gesture to cast a spell (seems less true in the 1990s on)
- Scarlet Witch: Must gesture to "cast" a hex; could only use power a limited number of times (especially in the 1960s)

So, in most cases, much less exotic than an alien radioactive element.

Side note: For years, Aquaman's weakness was that he could only be away from water for at most one hour. When Stan Lee and Jack Kirby created Triton (of the Inhumans), he required water to live (constantly, not just once an hour). However, he was relatively quickly (basically, in his second appearance) given a mechanism to allow him to live out of water. While he still had the weakness, I can't recall it playing a part in a story more than once or twice after that point. Of course, neither character generally would be considered as having "nigh-unlimited power", in most circumstances.

The piping and cuffs in his traditional outfit:

[image: Triton, drawn by George Perez, from *INHUMANS* (1875) #2]

are this mechanism, as can be seen here:

[image: Maximus frees Triton from water (*FANTASTIC FOUR* (1961) #54)]

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. But inside the X-Men universe there is Leech ([X-Men 3](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Leech), [Comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Leech_(Earth-616))), a mutant who cancels out the powers of other mutants near him.

In that same vein, there was the [mutant inhibitor collar](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Inhibitor_Collar), that rendered the wearer unable to use their mutant powers.

Comment: Also Scarlet Witch and Rogue can take away mutant powers.